# What are the real-valued functions?

Tags: functions

Is $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ a real-valued function?

I think the definition of a real-valued function is that the range is in the real numbers. Is that right?

Hence, I think $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ is not a real-valued function.

If then, what are the other examples of real-valued functions?

Are polynomial functions the only real-valued functions?

Comment: what non real value does $\frac{1}{x}$ take on?

Comment: By your definition, $f(x)=x^2$ is also not a real function because $-1$ is not in its range.

Answer (score 9):

A real valued is a function, whose range is $\mathbb{R}$ or some subset of $\mathbb{R}$.

$\frac{1}{x}$ for $x\in\mathbb{R}$ is real valued. We note that its range is $(-\infty,0)\cup (0,\infty)$, which is a subset of $\mathbb{R}$.

Polynomials are real valued, but they are not the only functions who are real valued.

A few examples of real valued functions:

The following are said to be real valued functions since their range is the set of real numbers, or some subset of the real numbers.

$f(x)=2$ ; The range is $\{2\}\subset \mathbb{R}$

$f(x)=11x$ ; The range is $\mathbb{R}$

$f(x)=e^x$ ; The range is $(0,\infty)\subset\mathbb{R}$

$f(x)=\dfrac{1}{x^2}$ ; The range is $(0,\infty)\subset \mathbb{R}$

etc...

Answer (score 8):

The term "valued" refers to a function's [codomain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codomain).  real-valued, complex-valued, integer-valued, vector-valued, etc.

Comment: Simple and straightforward.

Comment: I know I am late, but I wish I found this answer in my undergraduate days...

Answer (score 1):

**What is a real-valued function?**

> A real-valued function is a function that assigns real numbers to each member of its codomain or range.

**Is $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ a real-valued function?**

Yes because each member of the codomain of $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ is in fact a real number. Also note that excluding zero from the codomain does not change the fact that every other member is a real number. Symbolically, we have
$$f:\mathbb R\setminus\{0\}\to\mathbb R\setminus\{0\}$$
Since $\mathbb R\setminus\{0\}$ is a subset of $\mathbb R$, then the expression above can be read as $f$ is a real-valued function of a real-valued variable.

Comment: then is cos x is real valued function?

Comment: @aaa, $\cos(x+iy)$ is a real valued function when $y=0$ and also when $x=n\pi$, where $n$ is any integer.

Comment: In the function $f$, you have to exclude zero, right? One cannot have $1/0$.

Comment: @johnny09, Thanks for the correction, please see my edit.

Answer (score 0):

A function which has either $\mathbb{R}$ or one of its subsets as its range is called a real valued function. Further, if its domain is also either  $\mathbb{R}$ or a subset of  $\mathbb{R}$ it is called a real function.

Comment: Try formatting your responses using MathJax (http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).